# City proximity search drupal

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-7, geocoding

I need to implement a proximity search in Romania for articles based on the city name that has been inserted in a form field in a Drupal project. After browsing a lot of articles I see there are a lot of suggestions and solutions for zip codes and streets , but I only need the city geocodes ( lets say the center of that city ).
Where can I find such a database to insert into my project? Or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: What about the Geocoder module by Google? It uses the Google geocoding API.

Comment: Could you please provide a link for this module?

Comment: Of course. Here you are: https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder

Comment: Thanks , that should work:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) module to store the coordinates and then the [Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder) module to populate the geofield from the city field that you already have.

With Geocoder you can choose which service you want to use Google Geocoder, Yahoo, Bing etc

You can the use Gmap module or Open layers and Views to display your results.

Comment: Nice, I think this should work. Thank you very much for the help